# fabric.js - Multiuser canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am trying to create a canvas from fabric.js, and I am trying to create a multiuser canvas.

Everything works for now, although there is one problem:
The information is erased every time I am using the loadFromJSON() function.

Any idea how I could append information from the free drawing mode, without erasing information?

canvas is where I currently write the data, and canvas2 is where I need to APPEND the data to.

```
canvas.on('mouse:up', function() { 
console.log('mouse:up'); 
//console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas)); 
canvas2.loadFromJSON(JSON.stringify(canvas), canvas2.renderAll.bind(canvas2), function(o, object) {
    fabric.log(o, object);
});
canvas.clear();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with 2 ways
1st way :

```
canvas2.loadFromJSON(JSON.stringify(canvas), canvas2.renderAll.bind(canvas2), function(o, object){
canvas.clear();    
fabric.log(o, object);
});
```

2nd way :

```
var strCanvasContent = JSON.stringify(canvas)
canvas2.loadFromJSON(strCanvasContent, canvas2.renderAll.bind(canvas2), function(o, object) {
fabric.log(o, object);
});
canvas.clear();
```